# typeahead nested json object

Tags: json, ember.js, typeahead.js

I am new to Ember and JSON. I want to parse a JSON object that is below with typeahead library
and access nested object values by searching their keys.

I have this Json format:

```
return [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "Supermarket",
    "category_description": "SUPER MARKET",
    "image_url": "",
    "merchants": [
    {
      "name": "CARREFOUR",
      "id": 12,
      "merchant_type_id": 1,
      "merchant_type_description": "Gold",
      "merchant_redeption_rate": 0.002500,
      "image_url": "https://jpg",
      "branches": [
      {
        "id": 123456,
        "latitude": 37.939483,
        "area": "ΑΓ. ΔΗΜΗΤΡΙΟΣ",
        "zip": "12345"
      },
      {
        "id": 4567890,
        "longitude": 23.650622,
        "area": "ΑΓ. ΙΩΑΝΝΗΣ ΡΕΝΤΗΣ",
        "zip": "12345"
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "CAFCO",
      "id": 13,
      "merchant_type_id": 3,
      "merchant_type_description": "None",
      "merchant_redeption_rate": 0.002500,
      "image_url": "https:.jpg",
      "branches": [
      {
        "id": 127890,
        "latitude": 38.027870,
        "area": "ΠΕΡΙΣΤΕΡΙ",
        "zip": "12345"
      }
      ]
    }
    ]
  },


{
  "id": 2,
  "category_name": "Πολυκαταστήματα",
  "category_description": "ΠΟΛΥΚΑΤΑΣΤΗΜΑ",
  "image_url": "",
  "merchants": [
  {
    "name": "AGGELOPOYLOS CHR.",
    "id": 15,
    "merchant_type_id": 2,
    "merchant_type_description": "Silver",
    "merchant_redeption_rate": 0.002500,
    "image_url": "https://www.nbg.gr/greek/retail/cards/reward-programmes/gonational/PublishingImages/aggelopoulos.jpg",
    "branches": [
    {
      "id": 234780,
      "latitude": 35.366118,
      "longitude": 24.479461,
      "address": "ΕΘΝ. ΜΑΚΑΡΙΟΥ 9 & ΕΛ. ΒΕΝΙΖΕΛΟΥ 1",
      "area": "Ν. ΦΑΛΗΡΟ",
      "zip": "12345"
    }
    ]
  }
  ]
}


];
```

--------------------------**Updated**----------------------------

For example, i want to search using typeahead the name of merchants and when the letter we write to search matches the name of merchants it will appear the corresponding category_name and backwards.

Example -> when i keyboard the s it will appear :
Category : Supermarket,
Name: CARREFOUR
Name: CAFCO

And the same output on the dropdown of search when i keyboard the letter c.

Any help?

[New Jsbin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pacomiyano/4/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way (in my mind) to get this to work is to create a computed property that will contain an array of latitudes. But how do we get there?

To get to `latitude`, you need to go through array of `merchants` and then array of `branches`. Being that this will be across multiple elements, you are going to end up with "array of arrays" type data structure, which is annoying to deal with. So, to simplify this, we can create a simple `flatten` function as follows:

```
  flatten: function(origArray){
    var newArr = [];
    origArray.forEach(function(el) {
      el.forEach(function(eachEl){
        newArr.push(eachEl);
      });
    });

    return newArr;
  },
```

In addition to our function above, Ember already provides us with many other useful functions that can be used on arrays (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html)). One of those is `mapBy(property)` which transforms an array into another array only keeping the values of the property we specified.

So, to create a `lats` (for latitudes) property, we can just do this:

```
lats: function(){
  var merchantsArr = this.get('model').mapBy('merchants');
  merchantsArr = this.flatten(merchantsArr);
  var branchesArr = merchantsArr.mapBy('branches');
  branchesArr = this.flatten(branchesArr);

  return branchesArr.mapBy("latitude").compact();
}.property('model')
```

Above, I am basically using `mapBy`, `flatten` (see above) and `compact` which

> Returns a copy of the array with all null and undefined elements removed.

Once you have the `lats` property with all the necessary data, the rest is easy.

Your call to component becomes:

```
{{x-typeahead data=lats name='category_name' selection=myColor}}
```

Note `lats` instead of `model` you originally were passing into the component.

And now, to access the value of `data` property in the component, you do

```
`this.get('data')`
```

which you can just pass in as the `source` like so:

```
source: substringMatcher(self.get('data'))
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bilapa/1/edit?html,js,output)

**Update**

Updating my answer based on your updated question.

OK, so this is getting a little more complicated. You now need more than just one property (`latitude`) from the object. You need `category_name` and merchant `name`.

In addition to `mapBy`, which just grabs one property out of array, Ember also has `map` which lets you transform the array into pretty much anything you want to:

```
lats: function(){
  var merchantsArr = this.get('model').map(function(thing){
    var category_name = thing.category_name;
    return thing.merchants.map(function(merchant){
      return {
        "name": merchant.name,
        "category": category_name
      };
    });
  });

  merchantsArr = this.flatten(merchantsArr);

  return merchantsArr;
}.property('model')
```

The code above looks complicated, but it's basically just returning an array of top level objects' merchants accompanied by `category_name`. Since this is an array of arrays, we will need to flatten it.

Then, inside the component, we need to keep in mind that we are not just passing in an array of strings, but rather we are passing in an array of objects. Therefore, we need to look through object's properties (name and category) for a match

```
$.each(strs, function(i, str) {
  if (substrRegex.test(str.name) || substrRegex.test(str.category)) {
    matches.push(str);
  }
});
```

Lastly, to actually display both category and merchant name, you need to tell Typeahead how to do that:

```
templates: {
  suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{name}} – {{category}}</p>')
}
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wewiru/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are awesome! I edit my question with new data and new search functionality, If you have time take a look.